# Вывод компонента при нажатии на кнопку в боковом меню в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, компоненты

Я хотела сделать боковое меню, в котором при нажатии на каждую кнопку открывался бы свой компонент.  Для этого взяла готовый шаблон https://www.creative-tim.com/product/light-bootstrap-dashboard-react, в отдельном проекте он работает хорошо, но при попытке добавить это в свой проект (реакт 18 версии) возникают ошибки из-за разных версий. В итоге мне удалось убрать все ошибки и осталась одна проблема с роутингом: не могу понять или найти в интернете как это сделать в новой версии реакта. На старой версии переход по компонентам осуществлялся на этой строчке: `<Route path="/admin" render={(props) => <AdminLayout {...props} />} />`. Но при запуске проекта на 18 версии при переходе на `/admin` просто белый экран. Удалось сделать чтобы `/admin` открывалось корректно таким образом: `<Route path="/admin" element={<AdminLayout />} />`, но при нажатии на кнопки в боковом меню не происходит открытие компонентов, то есть посредине просто белый экран. При этом отдельно на странице эти компоненты открываются. Вопрос в том, как переписать эту строчку, чтобы компоненты выводились на страницу.

Вот как открывается страница сейчас (красным выделено где должны выводиться компоненты, например `dashboard`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот как должно открываться (если запускать отдельно с установленной нужной версией):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я думаю проблема в этой одной строке, о которой ранее шла речь. Ниже предоставляю минимальный код.

**index.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import App from "./App";
import Modal from "react-modal";

Modal.setAppElement("#root");

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(<App/>);
```

**App.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
...
import AdminLayout from "layouts/Admin.js";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/admin" element={<AdminLayout />} />
          {/* Рабочий вариант на старой версии */}
          {/* <Route path="/admin" render={(props) => <AdminLayout {...props} />} /> */}
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}
```

**Admin.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { useLocation, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

import AdminNavbar from "components/Navbars/AdminNavbar";
import Footer from "components/Footer/Footer";
import Sidebar from "components/Sidebar/Sidebar";
import FixedPlugin from "components/FixedPlugin/FixedPlugin.js";

import routes from "routes.js";

import sidebarImage from "assets/img/sidebar-3.jpg";

function Admin() {
  const [image, setImage] = React.useState(sidebarImage);
  const [color, setColor] = React.useState("black");
  const [hasImage, setHasImage] = React.useState(true);
  const location = useLocation();
  const mainPanel = React.useRef(null);
  
  const getRoutes = (routes) => {
    return routes.map((prop, key) => {
      if (prop.layout === "/admin") {
        return (
          <Route
            path={prop.layout + prop.path}
            render={(props) => <prop.component {...props} />}
            key={key}
          />
        );
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    });
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
    document.scrollingElement.scrollTop = 0;
    mainPanel.current.scrollTop = 0;
    if (
      window.innerWidth < 993 &&
      document.documentElement.className.indexOf("nav-open") !== -1
    ) {
      document.documentElement.classList.toggle("nav-open");
      var element = document.getElementById("bodyClick");
      element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    }
  }, [location]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="wrapper">
        <Sidebar color={color} image={hasImage ? image : ""} routes={routes} />  
        <div className="main-panel" ref={mainPanel}>
          <AdminNavbar />
          <div className="content">
            <Routes>{getRoutes(routes)}</Routes>
          </div>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </div>
      <FixedPlugin
        hasImage={hasImage}
        setHasImage={() => setHasImage(!hasImage)}
        color={color}
        setColor={(color) => setColor(color)}
        image={image}
        setImage={(image) => setImage(image)}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default Admin;
```

Comment: так а где, собственно, сам переход на этот компонент? это первое. А второе нужна главная страница path="/"

Comment: @Maneken главная страница есть, это просто вырезка из кода. Всё функционирует нормально, вопрос в том как переписать эту строку на новую версию.

Comment: короче, у меня так реализовано  https://github.com/dozzadore/itemsPatternsWebSite/blob/main/src/App.js

Comment: @Maneken я посмотрела, но там ведь все пути прописаны в основном файле в роутерах, а тут смысл в том, что данные компонентов хранятся в массиве, а именно ссылка, сам компонент, иконка и т.д. И потом данные берутся уже из этого массива, выводятся в левое меню и нажав на кнопку можно открыть компонент.

Comment: @Афродита проблема в том что как раз вы пытаетесь зачем-то реализовать роутинг через толстую кишку. Есть несколько способов реализовать защиту роутов (админ/модератор/пользователь/гость) но они все реализуются не тем что производится маппинг с массива, а тем что их отрезает некий Guard объект. Я бы лично завернул user permissions в контекст, и уже в guard реализовал наличие или отсутствие роута.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Открываем первый премер роутера со стражем.

https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/dev/examples/auth/src/App.tsx

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<Layout />}>
    <Route path="/" element={<PublicPage />} />
    <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
    <Route path="/protected" element={
      <RequireAuth>
        <ProtectedPage />
      </RequireAuth> } />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

И вам, и программисту после вас сразу понятно, что что-бы попасть в `/protected` нужно иметь доступы. Все роутеры в одном месте и никакой кашицы. Вообще хорошая реализация Guard есть у меня на codepen.

https://codepen.io/latdev/pen/qBJGmwr

Если чутка доработать напильником, то можно любые Permissions реализовать такие как

```
<Guard require="one" anyOf={[]} requireAll={[]} />
```

И использовать его не только в роутинге.

А еще расскажу по секрету, что в Guard можно запихнуть не только `<ProtectedPage/>` но и `<Route/>` целиком и даже массив из `<Route/>`

```
<Routes>
  <Route />
  <Route />
  <Guard require="admin" />
    <Route />
    <Route />
  </Guard>
</Routes>
```

Что мы получаем на выходе? Просто шикарный и читаемый код, с которым приятно работать без костылей с массивом.

Расскажу еще одну интересную фишку, что новый react-router-dom а именно 6.11 собирает роутер через массив и createBrowserRouter

https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial

Ps: Хотя лично меня вот конкретно так бесит в React что - они от версии к версии переделывают прям все целиком. И портировать код без боли и слез прям никак не получается особенно на крупных проектах.

Pss: react-modal кстати лучше сразу выкинуть в печь, и заменить его на HTML тэг Dialog - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog

**Добавлено 30.05**

Я так полагаю что с 6.х роутером вы столкнулись недавно, все эти вопросы автоматом отваливаются когда понимаешь что такое Outlet и вложенность Route. На ваше счастье на YT уже ответили на многие ваши вопросы.

Первая ссылка это пояснение Routes, Route, NavLink, Link

- https://youtu.be/0auS9DNTmzE

Вторая ссылка это рассказ о вложенности, layout и outlet

- https://youtu.be/ApftxkYnXdo

Вообще крайне рекомендую автора видео к просмотру! Он рассказывает умные и полезные вещи, причем не на уровне накрутить просмотры и поскорее отснять следующее говно, а именно выбирая темы по наростанию, и рассказывая разные нюансы. При этом он это делает по документации, и не несет чушь.

Comment: Так а как сделать вывод на страницу компонента после нажатия к примеру на кнопку в левом меню? В шаблоне, про который я писала, в каждом разделе (например dashboard) нету хедера, футера и т.д. То есть указан layot (это страница admin) и уже в него выводятся другие компоненты. Вот в этом вопрос, как переписать ту строчку кода, которая в старой версии работает, а в новой нет или какой аналог этой строчки. В интернете не могу найти пример как это реализовать, пыталась использовать шаблоны, практически везде ошибки при установке, вот этот шаблон встал нормально, но из-за старой версии проблемы.

Comment: Судя по коду в ответе это нужно импортировать каждую страницу и при переходе на определённый путь её выводить, то есть стандартный роутинг. Но тогда нужно будет на каждой странице добавлять в начале вот это левое меню, футер и т.д. А правильно ли это? Для начала хотелось бы разобраться просто с открытием компонентов, а уровни доступа это уже следующий этап, к тому же это не реальный проект, а просто попытка разобраться.

Comment: @Афродита дополнил свой ответ, парой интересных видео, которые помогут быстрее въехать в тему.

Comment: Да, по видео всё понятно стало, outlet это именно то что нужно было, спасибо большое!

Comment: Обращайтесь! Для этого и заходим. Делиться и получать новые знания!)